# ServiceBusTrigger using ReceiveDelete on a continous webjob

Tags: queue, azureservicebus, webjob

Is it possible to use a ServiceBusTrigger along with ReceiveDelete set for the ReceiveMode on a continous webjob? I have a message that takes longer than 10 minutes to process, so instead of using a peek I would like to just remove it from the queue as soon as the job picks up the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two options here:

1. Complete the message yourself
2. Use lock renewal API to extend the lock for more than 5 minutes using `maxAutoRenewDuration` of [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior).

Comment: So I ended up using host.CallAsync(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("Sync")); and removed my ServiceBusTrigger, and instead setup a queueClient to call  queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ReceiveMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);

So its processing the message off the queue fine, but is there a way for me to know which message is being processed? I need that message id to continue. Before I got it via the ServieBusTrigger

Comment: correction, that didn't work once I deployed it to azure, only works if I locally debug the console app.......it's not picking up the item on the queue correctly, I still think I need that ServiceBusTrigger

Comment: Creating your own queue client defeats the purpose of the WebJob/Function triggered by `ServiceBusTrigger`. The underlying implementation webjob/function with `ServiceBusTrigger` required PeekLock mechanism to complete messages on your behalf based on the execution status.

Comment: How exactly do I do the 2 options you mentioned? Any articles that could be of help?

Comment: Is it even possible to have an azure web job run for more than 10 minutes without it taking the same message off the queue? 
Is it possible to remove that message from the queue as soon as the job runs?

Comment: Option #1 will require to inject `MessageReceiver` into your Function. Once you have access to the `MessageReceiver` used to receive the message, you can complete the incoming message using `messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken)` method. With WebJob, depending on how you implement it, you will likely have a message receiver you'll instantiate and have a reference to, but would use the same approach.

Comment: Option #2 would require to use [`QueueClient.RegisterMessageHandler()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient.registermessagehandler?view=azure-dotnet). There's plenty of documentation on the web, including the official samples at https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet

Comment: I tried Option #1

Function.cs: 
        public async Task SyncTest([ServiceBusTrigger("syncqueue")] string message, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, string lockToken, TextWriter log)

I keep getting an error saying: 

Error indexing method 'Functions.SyncTest'
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException : Error indexing method 'Functions.SyncTest' ---> System.InvalidOperationException : 
Cannot bind parameter 'messageReceiver' to type MessageReceiver. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding.

Comment: @Mike, create a repro in GitHub and share a link. Sharing code and exception via comments is not going to work well.

Comment: I have injected `MessageReceiver` and it worked well. Here's the post BTW: https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/transactional-messaging-with-azure-functions-and-service-bus

Comment: https://github.com/justbringit85/synctest

I have created the GitHub as requested.

Comment: So what I just tried was using a BrokeredMessage instead of Message, removed the MessageReceiver and used the Complete() call within BrokeredMessage to remove item from the queue. So You pointed me in right direction, but not sure why Message didn't work for me. Maybe I'm using a different package?

Comment: You're using the old Azure Service Bus client (old version of the Azure Functions).